# Moodle package. Problem with definitions and environments

Tags: macros, definition

I'm compiling this simple quiz under LaTex TexShop 4.27

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{moodle}
\def\EN{{\bf A}}
\def\XV{3}
\def\YV{4}
%---------------------------
\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{MyQuiz}
\begin{essay}{Question A}
Report on study case \EN\  with numerical values:
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline
     $x$ & $y$  \\ \hline
     \XV & \YV  \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
  \item Case \EN\  with numerical values \XV,\YV
\end{essay}
\end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

and I get a nice pdf file. But inside the moodle.xml file the defined values don't appear anywhere and the body of the question is:

```
<text><![CDATA[<p>Report on study case \EN  with numerical values: <CENTER>\begin {tabular}{|c|c|} \hline \(x\) & \(y\) <BR/> \hline \XV & \YV <BR/> \hline \end {tabular}</CENTER> </p>]]></text>
```

producing this ugly result inside moodle:

[image]

What is happening with my definitions and the tabular environment ?.

Comment: change all the `\def` to `\newcommand` and it all compiles fine.

Comment: Section 4 of the manual lists the commands and environments that get translated into HTML; `tabular` is not among them, neither are, of course, your personal commands.

Answer (score 3):

This is what the package `moodle` documentation says; in particular, neither `tabular` nor your personal commands are supported.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the clarifying remark. I get confused since environments like \begin{array} work flawlessly and also in the introduction I read: "Users of LaTeX are also accustomed to the speed and flexibility that comes from defininf their own macros, which may be as brief as writting \R instead of \mathbb{R} or as complex as macros that generate entire paragraphs of text. The Moodel editor, by constrast, requires you to type \mathbb{R} every single time you want R"

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a tabular, the best solution I can see is to pack it into an image. For instance, see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/563517/228515).

However, for your macros, I figured out there is an undocumented utility to declare them for expansion by the package before writing in the XML file : `\htmlregister`. In your case, just place at the end of the preamble:

```latex
\def\EN{{\bf A}}
\def\XV{3}
\def\YV{4}
\htmlregister{\EN}
\htmlregister{\XV}
\htmlregister{\YV}
```

In a development version of the package, I introduced the command `\moodleregisternewcommands` which triggers the expansion of all macros subsequently defined using `\newcommand` (and the likes). See this [fixed issue](https://framagit.org/mattgk/moodle/issues/53). In this case, the use is:

```latex
\moodleregisternewcommands
\newcommand{\EN}{{\bf A}}
\newcommand{\XV}{3}
\newcommand{\YV}{4}
```