# Error uploading to Moodle when using the matrix environment

Tags: matrices, moodle

I'm trying to upload a Quiz for the first time to Moodle and I'm generating my files using the package{Moodle}. The problem is the uploaded file doesn't recognize the matrix environment and displayed the code instead of the matrix form. Is there a solution for that.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][c]{\hskip -\arraycolsep
\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols #1}}
\makeatother 
\usepackage{moodle}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{quiz}{Revisiting Linear Algebra}
     \begin{multi}[points=2]{Matrix Form of a Linear System}
       Consider the following system
              \begin{center}
       $
\begin{matrix}[r]
3.0 x_1    &+2.0 x_2     &+2.0  x_3      & -5.0 x_4 & =8 .0   \\
0.6 x_1   &+ 1.5 x_2     &+1.5 x_3       & -5.4 x_4 & =2.7 \\  
1.2 x_1   & -0.3 x_2      & -0.3 x_3      & 2.4 x_4   &  =2.1 , \\  
\end{matrix}
$
   \end{center}


which may be written as a single vector equation; i.e, $\mathbf{AB}=\mathbf{B}$.\\
     The $\mathbf{A}$ matrix associated with the  system is:
\item*
 $
\begin{bmatrix}[r]
3.0    &+2.0      &+2.0        & -5.0   \\
0.6    &+ 1.5      &+1.5        & -5.4   \\  
1.2    & -0.3      & -0.3      & 2.4 , \\  
\end{bmatrix}
$
\item $
\begin{bmatrix}[r]
8 .0   \\
2.7 \\  
2.1  \\  
\end{bmatrix}
$  
  \item $
\begin{bmatrix}[r]
x_1 &\\
x_2& \\  
x_3 &\\  
x_4 &\\
\end{bmatrix}
$       
\item  
$
\begin{bmatrix}[r]
3.0    &+2.0      &+2.0        & -5.0 &  8.0 \\
0.6    &+ 1.5     &+1.5       & -5.4  & 2.7 \\  
1.2    & -0.3      & -0.3       & 2.4 , & 2.1\\  
\end{bmatrix}
$       
\end{multi}

     \begin{multi}[points=2]{Matrix Form of a Linear System}
     Consider the following system
              \begin{center}
       $
\begin{matrix}[r]
3.0 x_1    &+2.0 x_2     &+2.0  x_3      & -5.0 x_4 & =8 .0   \\
0.6 x_1   &+ 1.5 x_2     &+1.5 x_3       & -5.4 x_4 & =2.7 \\  
1.2 x_1   & -0.3 x_2      & -0.3 x_3      & 2.4 x_4   &  =2.1 , \\  
\end{matrix}
$
   \end{center}


which may be written as a single vector equation; i.e, $\mathbf{AB}=\mathbf{B}$.\\
       The $\mathbf{B}$ matrix associated with the  system is:
\item*
       $
\begin{bmatrix}[r]
8 .0   \\
2.7 \\  
2.1  \\  
\end{bmatrix}
$  
\item[fraction=0] 
 $
\begin{bmatrix}[r]
3.0    &+2.0      &+2.0        & -5.0   \\
0.6    &+ 1.5      &+1.5        & -5.4   \\  
1.2    & -0.3      & -0.3      & 2.4 , \\  
\end{bmatrix}
$
  \item[fraction=0]   
 $
\begin{bmatrix}[r]
x_1 &\\
x_2& \\  
x_3 &\\  
x_4 &\\
\end{bmatrix}
$       
\item[fraction=0]   
 $
\begin{bmatrix}[r]
3.0    &+2.0      &+2.0        & -5.0 &  8.0 \\
0.6    &+ 1.5     &+1.5       & -5.4  & 2.7 \\  
1.2    & -0.3      & -0.3       & 2.4 , & 2.1\\  
\end{bmatrix}
$       
     \end{multi}     

 \end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

The [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/moodle/moodle.pdf) for `moodle.sty` (page 10) mentions that only four environments are recognized and converted to html: `center`, `enumerate`, `itemize` and `tikzpicture`. All other environments, such as `matrix`, therefore cannot be used. Quote (emphasis mine):

> Be aware that moodle.sty does not know how to convert any other TEX or
> LATEX commands to HTML. If other sequences are used, they may be
> **passed verbatim** to the XML file or may cause unpredicted results.

However, within a `tikzpicture` you can use LaTeX code inside of a `node`, which allows you to use the `matrix` environment. The matrices will be converted to images by Moodle and stored in base64 encoding in the `.xml` file, similar to including `.png` files for example.

Note that to make this work you may need to call `\tikzexternalize` explicitly in your quiz source code. Also `shell-escape` is required (same as with images).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][c]{\hskip -\arraycolsep
\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols #1}}
\makeatother 
\usepackage{moodle}
\usetikzlibrary{external} % set this 
\tikzexternalize          % explicitly

\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{Revisiting Linear Algebra}
\begin{multi}[points=2]{Matrix Form of a Linear System}
Consider the following system
       
\begin{tikzpicture} % matrix inside of tikzpicture node
\node{
$\begin{matrix}[r]
3.0 x_1    &+2.0 x_2     &+2.0  x_3      & -5.0 x_4 & =8 .0   \\
0.6 x_1   &+ 1.5 x_2     &+1.5 x_3       & -5.4 x_4 & =2.7 \\  
1.2 x_1   & -0.3 x_2      & -0.3 x_3      & 2.4 x_4   &  =2.1 , \\  
\end{matrix}
$};
\end{tikzpicture}

which may be written as a single vector equation; i.e, $\mathbf{AB}=\mathbf{B}$.\\
The $\mathbf{A}$ matrix associated with the system is:
\item*
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{ $
\begin{bmatrix}[r]
3.0    &+2.0      &+2.0        & -5.0   \\
0.6    &+ 1.5      &+1.5        & -5.4   \\  
1.2    & -0.3      & -0.3      & 2.4 , \\  
\end{bmatrix}
$};\end{tikzpicture}
\item\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{ $
\begin{bmatrix}[r]
8 .0   \\
2.7 \\  
2.1  \\  
\end{bmatrix}
$};\end{tikzpicture}  
  \item \begin{tikzpicture}
\node{$
\begin{bmatrix}[r]
x_1 &\\
x_2& \\  
x_3 &\\  
x_4 &\\
\end{bmatrix}
$};\end{tikzpicture}       
\item  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{$
\begin{bmatrix}[r]
3.0    &+2.0      &+2.0        & -5.0 &  8.0 \\
0.6    &+ 1.5     &+1.5       & -5.4  & 2.7 \\  
1.2    & -0.3      & -0.3       & 2.4 , & 2.1\\  
\end{bmatrix}
$};\end{tikzpicture}       
\end{multi}
 \end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

Part of the resulting xml:

```xml
<questiontext format="html">
    <text><![CDATA[<p>Consider the following system </P>
<P><IMG SRC="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAc4AAACOCAYAAAC4 etc.
```

Comment: Would it be possible to explain the the last step  "shell-escape " how can I  excute this step ? since I'm getting this error ! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -halt-on-error -interact

Comment: I used  \usepackage{graphicx} and the problem was solved

Answer (score 1):

The best practise solution seems to replace `matrix` with `array` one as proposed by the Moodle [manual](https://docs.moodle.org/310/en/Using_TeX_Notation), as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{moodle}
   \begin{document}
   \begin{quiz}{Revisiting Linear Algebra}
    
     \begin{multi}[points=2]{Matrix Form of a Linear System}
       Consider the following system
       \[
        \left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
3.0 x_1    &+2.0 x_2     &+2.0  x_3      & -5.0 x_4 & =8.0\\
0.6 x_1   &+ 1.5 x_2     &+1.5 x_3       & -5.4 x_4 & =2.7\\  
1.2 x_1   & -0.3 x_2      & -0.3 x_3      & 2.4 x_4   &  =2.1 , \\  
\end{array}\right]
\]
  
which may be written as a single vector equation; i.e, $\mathbf{AB}=\mathbf{B}$.\\
     The $\mathbf{A}$ matrix associated with the  system is:   
\item* First answer
\[
 \left[
\begin{array}{cccc}
3.0    &+2.0      &+2.0        & -5.0   \\
0.6    &+ 1.5      &+1.5        & -5.4   \\  
1.2    & -0.3      & -0.3      & 2.4 , \\
\end{array}
\right]
\]
\item Second answer
\end{multi}

 \end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

**Important note**: the currently published `moodle` package version 0.5 is outdated and has a bug that does not handle `\\`. You have to download the latest version from [here](https://gitlab.mattgk.myds.me/mattguer/moodle). Installation guidelines are [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6925/how-do-i-install-a-dtx-file/).