# I can't generate the file due to

Tags: tikz-styles, moodle

[image]I'm trying to generate this file but I'm getting an error that pdflatex-halt-on-error-inter...  I added the package  \usepackage{graphicx}, but its not working, any idea?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm, amssymb, latexsym}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\env@matrix[1][c]{\hskip -\arraycolsep
\let\@ifnextchar\new@ifnextchar
\array{*\c@MaxMatrixCols #1}}
\makeatother 
\usepackage{moodle}
\usetikzlibrary{external} % set this 
\tikzexternalize          % explicitly
\usepackage{graphicx}
 
\begin{document}
\begin{quiz}{Revisiting Linear Algebra}
\begin{multi}[points=2]{Matrix Form of a Linear System}
Consider the following system
       
\begin{tikzpicture} % matrix inside of tikzpicture node
\node{
$\begin{matrix}[r]
3.0 x_1    &+2.0 x_2     &+2.0  x_3      & -5.0 x_4 & =8 .0   \\
0.6 x_1   &+ 1.5 x_2     &+1.5 x_3       & -5.4 x_4 & =2.7 \\  
1.2 x_1   & -0.3 x_2      & -0.3 x_3      & 2.4 x_4   &  =2.1 , \\  
\end{matrix}
$};
\end{tikzpicture}

which may be written as a single vector equation; i.e, $\mathbf{AB}=\mathbf{B}$.\\
The $\mathbf{A}$ matrix associated with the system is:
\item*
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{ $
\begin{bmatrix}[r]
3.0    &+2.0      &+2.0        & -5.0   \\
0.6    &+ 1.5      &+1.5        & -5.4   \\  
1.2    & -0.3      & -0.3      & 2.4 , \\  
\end{bmatrix}
$};\end{tikzpicture}
\item\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{ $
\begin{bmatrix}[r]
8 .0   \\
2.7 \\  
2.1  \\  
\end{bmatrix}
$};\end{tikzpicture}  
  \item \begin{tikzpicture}
\node{$
\begin{bmatrix}[r]
x_1 &\\
x_2& \\  
x_3 &\\  
x_4 &\\
\end{bmatrix}
$};\end{tikzpicture}       
\item  
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node{$
\begin{bmatrix}[r]
3.0    &+2.0      &+2.0        & -5.0 &  8.0 \\
0.6    &+ 1.5     &+1.5       & -5.4  & 2.7 \\  
1.2    & -0.3      & -0.3       & 2.4 , & 2.1\\  
\end{bmatrix}
$};
\end{tikzpicture}       
\end{multi}
 \end{quiz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `tikz` loads `graphicx` already, so `\usepackage{graphicx}` is actually redundant.

Comment: he needs shell to be enabled, so what dose that mean ?

Comment: This is "pdflatex-shel-escape", this is part of the error

Comment: `-shell-escape` is an option to the `pdflatex` program allowing it to call other programs.  How you enable that depends on which editor you're using. That said, why do you have the matrices in  nodes in `tikzpicture`s in the first place?

Comment: I'm using TexMaker, this is a program that I received via this StackExchange, and I'm trying to run it.

Comment: Right, after reading [marjin's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/563517/) I understand that. For shell-escape, see if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/236641/ helps. If you don't have MikTeX you might need `-shell-escape` instead of `--enable-write18`, but otherwise the method should be the same.

Comment: I got an error that its not a known command when I added -shell-escape instead of  --enable-write18as the post said

Comment: I don't really know what's wrong. Can you show a screenshot of the Texmaker settings? Are you using MikTeX? (Texmaker is just the editor, you must have installed a TeX system in addition, which is either MikTeX, MacTeX or TeX Live.)